React Typewriter-effect doesn't work properly on mutation
in this code the new answer comes from a mutation function from tanstack query. I want an effect like chatgpt to run the code only if the answer is new but this simple typewriter won't run even without that functionality until I refresh the page.
I expected it to run without refresh for new answer just like mutation function
{chatsDetailsData?.map((data, index) => {
       const isLastIndex = index === chatsDetailsData.length - 1;
        return (
          <div
            key={data.id}
            className="py-2 px-3 text-base md:px-4 m-auto lg:px-1 xl:px-5 mb-6 text-[14px]"
          >
            <div className="mx-auto flex gap-3 lg:max-w-[48rem] lg:w-[48rem]">
              <div>
                {/* <img
                    className="w-32 lg:w-[40px] pt-[1.5px]"
                    alt="userlogo"
                  /> */}
                <svg
                  width="21"
                  height="27"
                  viewBox="0 0 40 40"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  {/* Background circle */}
                  <circle
                    cx="20"
                    cy="20"
                    r="20"
                    fill="rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3)"
                  />

                  {/* Text with the first letter */}
                  <text
                    x="50%"
                    y="50%"
                    textAnchor="middle"
                    dominantBaseline="middle"
                    fontSize="20"
                    fill="black"
                    fontFamily="Arial"
                  >
                    {data.user_frst_nm.charAt(0)}
                  </text>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                <div>
                  <p className="font-bold">{data.user_frst_nm}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-6 w-full">
                  <p>{data.question}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mx-auto flex gap-3 lg:max-w-[48rem] lg:w-[48rem]">
              <img
                className="h-[18px] mt-[3px]"
                src={logo}
                alt="userlogo"
              />
              <div
                className="flex flex-col gap-1 mb-[12px]"
                ref={bottomRef}
              >
                <p className="font-bold">Agent</p>
                {isLastIndex ? (
                  <Typewriter
                    onInit={(typewriter) => {
                      typewriter.typeString(data.answer).start();
                    }}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <TextProcessor inputText={data.answer} />
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  )}


React will redraw data only if state variables have been changed or new props have been received from higher-order components. Since objects and arrays are passed by links, mutation of these objects does not lead to data changes, because React will assume that the data has not changed (the link will remain the same)

Thanks, I knew this but surprisingly the typewriter component was rendered for every new answer, the problem was that the text didn't rendered properly. I've already fixed this and also made it like chatgpt with the use of states and the mutation function itself.
